# Assembly language variables

Tags: assembly, x86

What is the assembly language variable bl? How many bits does it hold? Is it a part of a larger variable like EBX?

Comment: You need to specify architecture.

Comment: EBX is not a variable but a register.

Comment: I'm running on a PC, not sure what architecture that's called. So does bl show a part of a register?

Comment: @ThiefMaster: registers are a type of variable, or most accurately, 'EBX' in assembly language is a variable that's implemented by the register called 'EBX'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EBX is the 32-bit variant

BX is the 16-bit variant

BH is the high byte of BX

BL is the low byte of BX

Comment: So if EBX=0000001B, then what is bl?

Comment: 1B is 32 bits, correct? Since each digit can go from 0 to F, which is 16 numbers. Does that mean that bl is a 32-bit variable?

Comment: @Phenom:No. Each hex digit can go from 0 to F. 16 numbers fit into 4 bits (2**4 = 16), so two hex digits correspond to 8 bits.